# Gmail smtp through mew

Tags: email, smtpmail

I am trying to setup mew to use a gmail account provided by my college. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and using emacs 25. This is my (anonymized) `.mew`:

```
(setq mew-config-alist
      '((default
          (mailbox-type          imap)
          (proto                 "%")
          (prog-ssl              "/usr/local/bin/stunnel")
          (imap-server           "imap.gmail.com")
          (imap-ssl-port         "993")
          (imap-user             "uname@student.college.tld")
          (name                  "Full Name")
          (user                  "uname")
          (mail-domain           "student.college.tld")
          (imap-ssl              t)
          (imap-size             0)
          (imap-delete           t)
          (imap-queue-folder     "%queue")
          (imap-trash-folder     "%Trash")
          (smtp-ssl              t)
      (smtp-auth             t)
          (smtp-auth-list        ("PLAIN" "LOGIN" "CRAM-MD5"))
          (smtp-user             "uname@student.college.tld")
          (smtp-server           "smtp.gmail.com")
          (smtp-ssl-port         "465")
      (use-cached-password   t)
      (ssl-verify-level      0)
      (prog-ssl-arg "fips=no\n"))))
```

The following is in my `.emacs` related to mew:

```
(autoload 'mew "mew" nil t)
(autoload 'mew-send "mew" nil t)
(setq read-mail-command 'mew)
(autoload 'mew-user-agent-compose "mew" nil t)
(if (boundp 'mail-user-agent)
    (setq mail-user-agent 'mew-user-agent))
(if (fboundp 'define-mail-user-agent)
    (define-mail-user-agent
      'mew-user-agent
      'mew-user-agent-compose
      'mew-draft-send-message
      'mew-draft-kill
      'mew-send-hook))
```

and the following in my `/ect/stunnel/stunnel.conf`:

```
[imaps]
accept = 993
connect = 143
[ssmtp]
accept = 465
connect = 25
```

However, mew hangs on `Creating an SSL/TLS connection` and I don't know why.

Edit: I am on mew 6.8, stunnel 5.44 and `stunnel /ect/stunnel/stunnel.conf` yields the following:

```
[ ] Clients allowed=500
[.] stunnel 5.44 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
[.] Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 
[.] Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6,SYSTEMD TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI Auth:LIBWRAP
[ ] errno: (*__errno_location ())
[.] Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
[.] UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
[.] FIPS mode disabled
[ ] Compression disabled
[ ] PRNG seeded successfully
[ ] Initializing service [imaps]
[!] Service [imaps]: TLS server needs a certificate`
```

edit2: Problem was resolved by adding `client=yes` under `ssmtp` in stunnel conf

Comment: Can we know please, what version of Mew, what version of Stunnel are you using? Can you run `stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf` from your command line and tell us what was the output?

Comment: edited post with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was resolved by simply adding `client=yes` under `ssmtp` in `stunnel.conf`